# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

My code is:

```
import { type } from '@testing-library/user-event/dist/type';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './clint.css'

export default function Addtask() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const obj = [{ task: text.trim(), id: task.length }];

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      setTask([...task, obj[obj.length-1].task]);
      const resp = await fetch(
        'http://localhost:5000/addtask',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(task),
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      );
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        console.log('task added successfully');
      } else {
        console.log("unable to post");
      }          
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }

  function change(e) {
    const ip = e.target.value;
    setText(ip);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>add user component</h1>
 
      <span>Add Task</span>
      <input onChange={change} placeholder='add a task' />
      <button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>submit</button>
      <ul>
        {task.map((tasks, i) => 
          <li key={i}>
            {tasks}
            <button
              className='delete'
              onClick={() => {
                const removeItem = task.filter(() => {
                  return obj[i].id !==  i;
                });
                setTask(removeItem);
                console.log(i)
              }}
            >
              <b>X</b>
            </button>
          </li>
        )}                
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The error is coming:

> ```
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
>   at http://localhost:3000/main.158d69bbe90ec71b22a6.hot-update.js:94:29
>   at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
>   at onClick (http://localhost:3000/main.158d69bbe90ec71b22a6.hot-update.js:93:37)
>   at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29605:18)
>   at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29649:20)
>   at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29706:35)
>   at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError 
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29720:29)
>   at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33864:7)
>   at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33890:11)
>   at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33901:9)
> ```

Why am I not able to delete the tasks from the todo list? When I am clicking the 'X' icon to delete the tasks this error is coming saying that cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id'). I have tried many approaches but nothing is working properly in most of the cases this error is coming.

Comment: Try this "const removeItem =task.filter((_, index) => {index !== 
                i;});"

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`obj` is declared each render cycle and is an array with only 1 element, e.g. it's an array of length 1. When the `tasks` array is mapped and you click the delete button of any task *after* index 0, then the `i` index value indexes out of bounds on the `obj` array. In other words, when `i` is any value *other than* 0, `obj[i]` is undefined and the code can't access an `id` property of an undefined value.

## Solution

If you are needing to remove an element from the `task` state array, then filter the tasks that have `id` property that isn't the same as that of the task you would like removed. Also, since the `task` state is an array of tasks I *highly* recommend renaming it `tasks` so it's clearer what its use case and purpose is.

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

...

<ul>
  {tasks.map((task) => (
    <li key={task.id}> // <-- use task id as React key
      {task.task}      // <-- task is object, task.task is text
      <button
        className='delete'
        onClick={() => {
          // filter all tasks that have a different id than this task
          setTask(tasks => tasks.filter(taskEl => taskEl.id !== task.id));
        }}
      >
        <b>X</b>
      </button>
    </li>
  )}                
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

the way i’ve found to get try to get a value when that happens is by using

```
object?.value
```

or by using

```
object['value']
```

those have helped me in the past, good luck with the problem